# Хранение логина, пароля и URL для Hibernate в отдельном файле

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

Работая с Hibernate (Не в спринге!!!!!), мне, как и многим из вас, лень настраивать БД вручную. Приятно использовать автоматический поиск файлов в проекте и автоконфигурацию. Все бы ничего, но тут потребовалось новый проект выставить на Github, но вот логина,пароля и URL показывать не хочется.

Требуется пример кода, в котором Hibernate будет брать основной файл и файл с секретными данными и автоконфигурироваться при запуске программы.

На данный момент я использую `hibernate.cfg.xml`, но ответы с `application.properties` тоже принимается.

Пример моего (рабочего) кода:

## HibernateUtil.java:

```java
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                // Create registry
                registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

                // Create MetadataSources
                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

                // Create Metadata
                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

                // Create SessionFactory
                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (registry != null) {
                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        if (registry != null) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }
}
```

#### hibernate.cfg.xml:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <!--SERVER-->
        <!--<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useSSL=false&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;</property>-->
        <property name="connection.username">USERNAME</property>
        <property name="connection.password">PASSWORD</property>

        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout">20000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout">300000</property>


        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <!--<property name="show_sql">true</property>-->

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <!--<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>-->
        <!--<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>-->
        <!--<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>-->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        <!-- dbcp connection pool configuration -->
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxTotal">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWaitMillis">-1</property>

        <!--<mapping class="entities.User" />-->
        <!--<mapping class="entities.Servers" />-->
        <!--<mapping class="entities.Authorities" />-->
        <!--<mapping class="entities.Language" />-->
        <!--<mapping class="entities.ServerMessage" />-->
        <!--<mapping class="entities.MessageServer" />-->


    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Вы совсем не используете Spring? Или просто у вас старые версии где он еще не так сильно интегрирован?

Comment: @zdadco Hibernate можно использовать и без спринга. Стоит отметить, что в моем вопросе `Spring` нигде не упомянут. Приведенный выше код - это код, которым я пользуюсь вне спринга. Увы, я пока не нашел в интернете правильной настройки `HibernateUtil` с `application.properties`/`hibernate.cfg.xml`

Comment: Я понимаю что его можно использовать без спринга, просто если у вас в проекте все-таки он есть, то вам доступен PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. По этому и спрашиваю, но видимо у вас полностью отсутствует спринг.

Comment: @zdadco Если есть варик для спринга - добавьте его, пожалуйста.

Comment: До сих пор не уверен, что это то, что вам действительно нужно, но гляньте вот на это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939339/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-with-hibernate-cfg-xml

Comment: @zdadco Данный пример больше под спринг с `xml`-настройками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Данный ответ будет модифицироваться.*

Отдельно спасибо за помощь [zdadco](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/331670/zdadco) при нахождении ответов на данный вопрос.

### Spring + Hibernate (+ Maven)

Если вы используете Спринг + Hibernate, то делаем следующим образом:

1. В папке `Resources` (где лежит файл `application.properties`) создаем файл `database.properties`
2. В данный файл помещаем, к примеру, следующие данные:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=DRIVER
spring.datasource.url=URL
spring.datasource.username=USERNAME
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD
```

2. В главном классе (запускаемом  классе) добавляем следующую строчку `@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")`, чтобы у нас в итоге получилось вот так:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class Launch{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Launch.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если не использовать инструментарий Spring или любую другую возможность выноса настроек в отдельные properties файлы то можно сделать следующее:

Создаете копию hibernate.cfg.xml, называете его произвольно, например hibernate.mock.cfg.xml. В этом файле меняете пароль и имя на заглушки. В gitignore добавляете оригинальный hibernate.cfg.xml файл.

Тогда блок объявления SessionFactory будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
       if (sessionFactory == null) {
          try {
               sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
          } 
               catch (ConfigurationException noConfEx)
          {
               sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.mock.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
          }
          catch (Throwable ex) {
               throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
          }
   return sessionFactory;
}
```

Код выше работает следующим образом: когда вы пытаетесь достать hibernate.cfg.xml которого в гите нет, то конфигурация будет считана из заглушки. Таким образом для решения задачи мы используем стандартную опцию разноса конфига в гибернейте. Подробнее про это можно почитать тут: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

В качестве альтернативы по похожему приницпу:

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
           if (sessionFactory == null) {
              try {
                   sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
              .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", LoginHandler.getUserName())
              .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", LoginHandler.getPassword())
              .buildSessionFactory();
              } 
              catch (Throwable ex) {
                   throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
              }
       return sessionFactory;
    }
```

В этом случае вам надо будет написать класс LoginHandler который будет доставать нужные логин и пароль из правильных мест (например из разных properties).

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в проект properties файл. Наприм `dbParams.properties` куда запиши адрес, порт, логин и пароль. При запуске доставай данные из этого файла и создавай подключение через `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`. А сам properties файл огородь в .gitignore чтобы не заливался на github. Его передавай нужным людям любым защищённым способом.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, привести рабочий код, на примере моего кода выше?

Comment: @Antonio112009 Можно сделать гораздо проще. Не подумал. В .gitignore добавьте строчку 
`hibernate.cfg.xml`. И он не будет заливаться в репозиторий. Но без него проект и не запустить. Храните и передавайте его отдельно защищенным 
 и удобным для вас способом.

Comment: Да, но хотелось бы все-таки выставить данный файл, но без URL, логина и пароля, потому что в том файле есть важные настройки, а писать в `readme.md`, что надо добавить в данный файл, мне бы не хотелось

Comment: @Antonio112009 А это уже вряд ли получится. Нельзя доставать настройки сразу из двух источников. Либо xml, либо вручную прописывать параметры.

Comment: Окей, Как тогда сделать на примере `application.properties`?